# SSRS report - export from C# without SSRS server

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to export a ssrs report from C#. Report is running using ReportViewer in a local mode with no SSRS server available. I have gone through many examples. Seems like they are all showing code when SSRS report is in place. If no export with no SSRS server is not possible, can I at least use the following
[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2016#ReportExecution2005_ReportExecutionService_Render_System_String_System_String_System_String__System_String__System_String__ReportExecution2005_Warning____System_String____)

which shows how SSRS web Services endpoints can be used.
I am not a C# developer so I dont know if it's possible to use SSRS web services without installing the SSRS server somewhere.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You are making a connection to a database and want to return a HTML report.  Normally the database has a tool that creates reports in HTML format.  You can write your own HTML formatter with any type data in c#.  The following webpage connects to a SQL server, but you do not need to connect to a database to create a report.  Just need input data.  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-create-an-html-report-by-using-inline-code-in-Asp-Net/?force_isolation=true

Comment: No, I need to use SSRS report that is processing in the backend using ReportViewer.

Comment: If yo need SSRS than you have to use a SQL Server.  The app is built into a SQL Server.

Comment: As I said, we can run a report without SSRS Server. It runs in ReportViewer (Local Mode) and processing takes place on the server. And that is where I want to export report into Excel.

Comment: I think this article might be useful. The sample report connects to a database but that's only for the report's data. It does not appear to use an SSRS server, just a local rdlc.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/export-rdlc-report-to-excel-without-using-reportviewer-in-aspnet-with-c-and-vbnet.aspx

Comment: Yes, seems like that is what I need. Question: do you know if the followwing header: Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=RDLC." & extension) will download the report with a name "RDLC.PDF" for PDF?

Comment: That's correct, although the file name is just a literal `RDLC` in this case. There is a demo button below the code so you can see it running.

Comment: Great. Just one question. The downloaded file is "xls" which is the old Excel version. Is it possible to create "xlsx" version?

Comment: What if I need to download multiple files with one request? How would "Content-Disposition" actually work if I add multiple "Content-Disposition" headers?

Comment: I've never actually done this, I just found the article with a quick search. You really need to just start new question(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible.
im using reportviewer for local reportprocessing to generate pdfs from rdl files. its along the line of how you can use it.

in my experience this approach can cause issues with multithreading

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using Warning = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning;
```

---

```
                var viewer = new ReportViewer { ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local };
            var localReport = viewer.LocalReport;
            localReport.LoadReportDefinition([stream from rdl]);
            localReport.DataSources.Clear();
            localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource
                {
                    Name = dataSet.Name,
                    Value = [USE DATATABLE THAT HAS THE SAME STRUCTURE THAN YOUR DATASOURCE]
                });
                
            Warning[] warningslocal = null;
            string encoding;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType;
            string extension;
             var result = localReport.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
                out streamIds, out warningslocal);
```